# What is the most pythonic way to exclude a special value from an iterator?

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator

As an example. Lets say I have a grid-based game, where the player agent can walk to all squares around the current position, but not stay still.

Thus we could see each move as a tuple (dx,dy), with the total set of moves being
`[(1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,1), (0,-1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1)]`
Staying still would be (dx,dy) = `(0,0)`.

With this problem in mind, one could make use of the cartesian product of [1,0,-1] with itself, which in Python would be `itertools.product(iterables*)`. However, this would yield all those tuples listed above, *including* `(0,0)`

One solution is to convert it to a list, and then use `remove()` on the list:

`steps = list(itertools.product([-1,0,1],[-1,0,1])).remove((0,0))`
or alternatively `[x for x in itertools.product([1,0,-1], [1,0,-1]) if x != (0,0)]`. Both of these solutions require conversion to lists.

What's your cleanest way to yield and exclude `(0,0)`?

Comment: You could make it slightly simpler by rearranging your input lists so that the unwanted (0,0) tuple is the very first (or very last) element of the result.  You could then exclude it by slicing.  (Note that the code you showed won't actually work, since `.remove()` doesn't return the list.)

Comment: Thanks for the response @jasonharper. That does work in this case, although I meant it more as an example of what I mean. So I'm looking for a general way to exclude values that a iterator may yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you would define another iterator based on the first one and apply a condition in a comprehension.

In this case:

```
moves = ( p for p in itertools.product((-1,0,1),repeat=2) if p != (0,0) )
```

Here `moves` is a new generator that will filter out (0,0) from the output of itertools.product.  *Notice that it is enclosed in parentheses, not square brackets which would make it a list instead of an iterator*

Comment: Thank you Alain, this is perfect! It gives a general solution that I was looking for (as per the title).

Answer (score 1):

This question probably falls into the category of *opinion-based* and could be closed, but the cleanest way would be to strictly enumerate the valid values as you have already done. Explicitly stating the values is more readable than jamming their generation into a one-liner, especially as they seem to be constant. You can even format the code to improve readability (assuming a tool like `black` will leave it alone).

```py
VALID_MOVES = (
    (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
    (-1, 0),         (1, 0),
    (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1)
)
```